# LINQ Contains() alternatives

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have a list of `int` and I need to select all record from my query where the id is contained in the second list as showed below:

```
     //my list of ids
    var ids=[myquery].select(x=> x.id)

    query = query.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id));
```

Now LINQ will convert the above in :

```
SELECT *
FROM [MyTable] 
WHERE ([x].[id] IN (108,687, 689, 691, 694, 705, 703,.....)
```

Now the ids list will grow a lot and I guess this will ruin the performances.

What would be a better solution considering the the `ids` list will contain more than 200K item ?

Comment: probably you should use a navigation property, but it depends what `[myquery]` and `query` are.

Comment: You need to send those 200K items some way. Linq converting to such IN (...) is fine. I had the same need, with a slight difference where my ID list was available as a comma separated list (string). I ended up creating a CLR function (MS SQL Server).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your model, but you should probably use a navigation property.

Given that you currently have something like this:

```cs
var ids =
   context
   .Entity1
   .Where(x => x.Property == value)
   .Select(x => x.ID)
   .ToHashSet();

var items =
   context
   .Entity2
   .Where(x => ids.Contains(x.ID))
   .ToList();
```

write something like this instead:

```cs
var items =
   context
   .Entity2
   .Where(x => x.Entity1.Property == value)
   .ToList();
```

You may need to add such an association to your model before this will be possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a stored procedure as:

- there is no unnecessary calls between C# and database(e.g., you are collecting these 200K `ids`)
- less code in C#. So your code will be cleaner and clearer
- performance is better as sometimes EF generates inefficient SQL code

So [calling stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) would look like this:

```
var user = "johndoe";

var blogs = context.Blogs
    .FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE dbo.GetMostPopularBlogsForUser {0}", user)
    .ToList();
```

OR  try to use `NOT IN` operator if items are less `200K`:

```
query = query.Where(x => !ids.Contains(x.Id));
```

SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM [MyTable] 
WHERE ([x].[id] NOT IN (108,687, 689, 691, 694, 705, 703,.....)
```